# how can I chop letters of a string into smaller chunks of fixed lengths in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read. I am a total beginner and I know this might sound one of those "help me understand this" questions but I'm sorry if that was the case and I'll try to be specific as much as I can.

Basically I need to create a function to chop strings into smaller strings of input length, I have tried array methods but for some reason I keep getting an empty array. So that the if the input string is "hell" and the input length is 2 the output would be ["he","ll]

Also, in relevance to this problem, I was wondering if you can set a for loop condition x.length<=0.

Here is my code:

```
function chop(a, b) { 
    // a = "hell"
    // b = 2

    var ans = [];
    var x = a.split(""); // [h,e,l,l]

    for (var i = 0; i<=(x.length/b); i++) { 
        // condition i<=2
        // I was also wondering how can set the condition to be x.length <= 0

        x  = x.slice(0,(b-1));  // x = "he"
        ans.push(x); // ans = ["he", ]
        x = x.splice(0,b); // x = [l,l]

    }

    console.log(ans);

}
```

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code nicely. Thanks.

Comment: yeah I guess that's why I keep getting downvotes on my questions please let me know how can I make it better? 
I guess you've read that I'm a beginner and I'm also new to stackoverflow, so I would appreciate any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function chop(a, b) {

  var ans = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += b) {
    ans.push(a.substring(i, i + b));
  }
  console.log(ans);   
}

chop("hello", 2);  //logs ["he", "ll", "o"]
```

Comment: I just don't understand why there is   i+=b not i++  in the for loop?

Comment: first `iteration` it is `i=0`  `a.substring(0,2)` ,  second=> `i is now 0+2(b)=2` and `a.substring(2,4)`, third=> `i is now 2+2(b)=4`, `a.substring(4,6)` ,forth=> `i is now 4+2(b)`, `a.substring(6,8)`.. and so on

Comment: ahh your explanation made it much easier. thank you so much itsgoingdown

Answer (score 2):

It's simple if you use regular expressions:

```
"hello".match(/.{1,2}/g) || []; // ["he", "ll", "o"]
```

However, if you don't know the value of the second parameter beforehand, it's a bit more dirty:

```
function chop(a, b) {
  return a.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+b+'}','g')) || [];
}
chop("hello", 2); // ["he", "ll", "o"]
```

In that case, it would be a good idea to sanitize `b` before inserting it in the regex.